# C++/CLI & Inconsistent layout information in duplicated types (std._Tree_unchecked_const_iterator)

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2017, c++-cli

I have got an issue after using the Platform Toolset v141 in Visual Studio 2017 for Debug 64 bit compilation.

```
typedef std::map<int, msclr::gcroot<cli::array<short>^>> MapIntToManaged;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    MapIntToManaged testMap;
    for (auto &it : testMap) {}

    return 0;
}
```

This results in the linker error

```
error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (8013118D) : Inconsistent layout information in duplicated types (std._Tree_unchecked_const_iterator< ?? :: ?? >): (0x02000048).
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1255: link failed because of metadata errors
```

I found a couple of workarounds to get rid of this error:

- changing the Platform Toolset back to v140
- using this syntax instead of the **auto** iterator:

  ```
      for (MapIntToManaged::iterator it = testMap.begin(); it != testMap.end(); ++it) {}
  ```
- changing the Runtime Library from Multi-threaded **Debug** DLL (/MD**d**) to Multi-threaed DLL (/MD) and use NDEBUG instead of _DEBUG as preprocessor define
- using 32 bit instead of 64 bit

I'd like to understand this issue.
And I want to use the newest toolset, the new iterator syntax and the Debug runtime DLL.

Comment: Seems to me like a bug. I tried it (adding includes for <msclr/gcroot> and <map>) and it worked for x86 in debug and release but not for x64 debug.

Comment: Use Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem to let them know.  Seems to have something to do with the iterator debugging feature, defining `_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING=0` solves it.  Well, you have enough workarounds.